# AChartEngine Messed up labels

Tags: date, time, scroll, achartengine

My chart displays fine but as soon as I scroll to the side, I have random time appearing and it messes up the dates, see this picture:
http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/8329/statqs.jpg

I'd like to only display the date and nothing else, I don't know how the renderer comes up with time that I never entered.

Also I'd like to know how I can prevent scrolling to the left (x axis) and down (negative y), I can no longer use SetPanLimits because my x values are dates and not numbers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have the same problem. Could u tell me if u solve it,plx? thx

Comment: Me too, someone might say me how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very old, but for the next user, it may help to have the solution.

You can specify the date format to use

```
/**
 * Creates a time chart intent that can be used to start the graphical view
 * activity.
 * 
 * @param context the context
 * @param dataset the multiple series dataset (cannot be null)
 * @param renderer the multiple series renderer (cannot be null)
 * @param format the date format pattern to be used for displaying the X axis
 *          date labels. If null, a default appropriate format will be used.
 * @return a time chart intent
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if dataset is null or renderer is null or
 *           if the dataset and the renderer don't include the same number of
 *           series
 */
  public static final Intent getTimeChartIntent(Context context, XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset,
  XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer, String format) {
        return getTimeChartIntent(context, dataset, renderer, format, "");
  }
```

To show only day and month, use something like the following:

```
Intent intent = ChartFactory.getTimeChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer, "dd-MMM");
```