# SetPanLimits() with dates in the axis Achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a graph where the information in the x Axis are dates. I want to limit the pan but I don't know how to do it with dates!

I found this question but has no answer yet!

[AChartEngine Messed up labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540841/achartengine-messed-up-labels)

Thanks!

Solution: I did it in a very ugly way, so if anyone comes out with a better idea I would be happy to hear. What I did:

```
double[] limits = new double[] {xMin-(81300000 *3),xMax+(81300000 *3),yMin,yMax};
```

This way I limit it to three days before and after my first and last date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That solution's what I did too.  Just set a static final double at the top of the graph activity

```
private static final double THREEDAYS = 86400000 *3;
```

then

```
double[] limits = new double[] {xMin-THREEDAYS ,xMax+THREEDAYS ,yMin,yMax};
```

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit late to the party but why 81300000 and not 86400000 (=1000*3600*24)?

Comment: Dreamcooled, you're absolutely right.  I just took the value from the original question and didn't check it